# Flutter Firebase does not persist user authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an app using Firebase google authentication in Flutter. I was able to sign in to the app, but when I close the app, the authentication is removed which required me to sign in again.

This is my login screen, 'Sign in with Google' button will trigger the onPressed() in _signInButton().

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auth_screen/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:auth_screen/homepage.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage("assets/thelogo.jpg"), height: 200.0),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
             _signInButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed: () {
        signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return MyHomePage();
              },
            ),
          );
      });
      },
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
      highlightElevation: 0,
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(image: AssetImage("assets/google_logo.png"), height: 35.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Sign in with Google',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the page where all Google and Firebase perform authentication.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

String name;
String email;
String imageUrl;

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {

  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  imageUrl = user.photoUrl;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  //return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}

void signOutGoogle() async{
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
  theID = '';
  print("User Sign Out");
}
```

I heard that by default Firebase will persist user auth, but it doesn't happen in my program. Is there any method for making the user authentication persist until I press the log out button? Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does store persist auth, you just need to call it!!

There are two ways to approach this:

1. **Without Shared_pref** -  In this method, you create a splash screen, which is the entry point of your app(add app logo or something here) and in that where you check if a user is logged in then send him to the main screen or else send him to the login screen.

```
Future<void> _handleStartScreen() async {
    Auth _auth = Auth();

    if (await _auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
    } else {
      Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, WelcomeScreen.id);
    }
  }
```

You can call it from initstate of the splash screen.

2.**With Shared_pref**:- this is the more commonly used way. In this, you store auth state locally in-app with the use of a package shared_preferences(https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-, you can check how to use it from the given link)
So whenever a user logs in, store a bool in it with `logged_in = true`, and whenever the app starts you call the instance of shared_preferences from your splash screen.
you can toggle the logged_in var when he logs out.

Comment: Glad that it helped your query!!

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023, Firebase Auth Flutter documentation states that, it's persistent by default and not configurable on iOS and Android.

```
The Firebase SDKs for all platforms provide out of the box support for ensuring that your user's authentication state is persisted across app restarts or page reloads.

On native platforms such as Android & iOS, this behavior is not configurable and the user's authentication state will be persisted on-device between app restarts. The user can clear the apps cached data via the device settings which will wipe any existing state being stored.
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/)

Based on the answer you've accepted, I think problem is that you are not manually handling the page changes.

You can use authStateChanges or userChanges stream with StreamBuilder, or you can even use go_router redirects based on this stream. I suggest you to use stream, so app can be more dynamic and you can handle if current user is dropped(became null, logout etc.)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUserStream = FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges();

    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: firebaseUserStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            // Show login page if the user is not logged in
            return LoginPage();
          } else {
            // Show home page if the user is logged in
            return HomePage();
          }
        } else {
          // Show a progress indicator while waiting for the stream
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

GoRouter example can be long but to sum up that approach:

- I'm using singleton AuthBloc, with get_it and injectable
- AuthBloc listens userChanges stream and emit state based on that, like authenticated, unauthenticated.
- Since blocs have stream, I'm telling GoRouter to listen that.

  ```
   final router = GoRouter(
     refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(getIt<AuthBloc>().stream),
     routes: [//some routes here]
     redirect: (context, state) async {
       final authState = getIt<AuthBloc>().state;
       final isUnauthenticated = authState is! Authenticated;
       final isAuthenticated = authState is Authenticated;
        // code where I return correct page based on Auth and other stuff.
      },
  ```